# Update process freezes from 2.11.8 to 2.11.9, what do I do now?

Tags: ee2-upgrades, update, updating, ee2.11

This is an urgent issue, because it concerns a MSM site with three live sites. I try to update to the latest 2.xx version but the installer freezes in the process, to be exactly from 2.11.8 to 2.11.9 .

What do I do now?
Who can possibly help me out here?

thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you post a clipping of the error message you receive when the update freezes?

Comment: No error message at all, just a blank screen. Just looked in the database, the last entres in update_log are: 'Preparing to update from 2.11.8 to 2.11.9. Awaitin...' and 'Updating to 2.11.9' I think I changed all addons to the latest, what can I do more?

Comment: in my config file the app version is '$config['app_version'] = '2.11.8';'

Comment: If you are getting a 'white screen of death' then most likely it is an add-on that is causing problems.  One solution is to un-install all the add-ons, do the upgrade and then add them back.  But make sure you have a good back up of the EE2.11.8 version of the site (or even better do the upgrade on a duplicate of the site on a development server).

Comment: By uninstalling addons you mean remove from the server I guess? And then put them back one by one again?

Comment: The problem was pinned down to one add-on unfit for this system. By removing all of them (moving them on the server in a separate directory) and replacing one after the other I could test the whole site.  jcogs.eecms can you please post an answer? I can accept that then so we can close this. Thank a lot for helping!

Comment: Glad you got it sorted :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are getting a 'white screen of death' then most likely it is an add-on that is causing problems.

One solution is to un-install all the add-ons, do the upgrade and then add them back. (simply move all the third-party add-ons from the directory they are in to a different one, do the upgrade, and move them back one at a time until you work out which one is causing the problem).

But make sure you have a good back up of the EE2.11.8 version of the site (or even better do the upgrade on a duplicate of the site on a development server).